# Rails on EC2 - Puma responds, but page never loads on browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, server, puma

Firstly, cheers! This is my first post here on Stack Overflow, I'll try not to do anything silly :). I've spent the last 3 days banging my head against this issue and googleing away, but never really found a solution, however basic it may be.

I've set up a fresh EC2 instance (running Ubuntu 16.04) and created a new Rails (v 5.1.6) app with a simple scaffold:

```
rails new test_app
cd test_app
```

At this point, Rails complained that I had to install the 'listen' gem, which I did (v 3.1.5). I then proceeded as follows:

```
rails g scaffold article title:string
rails db:create
rails db:migrate
```

So far so good. I then went on to configure AWS's security groups and properly allow TCP connections through port 3000. I'm currently using Puma  (v 3.7) as a server.

Here's whats bugging me: I then ran

```
rails server
```

and tried to connect to my EC2 through Chrome on port 3000. Turns out that I was able to get to the usual "You're on Rails" page, no problem, **but when I tried to get to any other pages**, say /articles or /articles/new, **I got a positive response from the server** in the console:

```
Started GET "/articles" 
Processing by ArticlesController#index as HTML
Rendering articles/index.html.erb within layouts/application
Article Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles"
Rendered articles/index.html.erb within layouts/application (47.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 3912ms (Views: 3807.5ms | ActiveRecord: 1.5ms)
```

**But the browser keeps waiting forever for a response.** I also tried accessing the URL through curl and got no response as well. I'd appreciate if anyone could let me know how stupid a mistake I'm making here.

Thanks,

Márcio

Answer (score 0):

***Firstly, cheers you explained your problem very well***

when you deploying your app on EC2 then this isn't the right way to do but still it should give you response in browser. Please make sure your port 3000 isn't blocked. Go to **network interface** -> **select your instance carefully** -> in front of Security groups check your inbound rules and make sure port 3000 is open

Above explanation is just to answer whatever you are trying to do. Although this should not be the proper way. Proper way should (in short ) be running your ruby on rails application with a rack server (puma, thin, etc) behind a web server Apache or Nginx .

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply! Indeed, I was originally planning on using Nginx as a web server, but since I was getting this bizarre behaviour, I tried to create a minimal app and see if I would still get the error. I did check the security groups as you suggested, and it seems that port 3000 is wide open (I've added both 0.0.0.0/0 and ::/0 to the CIDR field). Do you think this might be a firewall issue?